# Data from mockAPI not showing correctly in Angular 8 UI

Tags: html, angular, api, frontend, angular8

I have a mockAPI and it is fetching the data correctly. The json response is complicated and is of type:

```
    [
  {
    "planList": [
      {
        "memberCost": {
          "memberResponsibility": "342",
          "totalCostofOwnership": "35",
          "serviceCategory": [
            {
              "benefitCategoryId": "63GD",
              "cost": "A,B,C",
              "benefitCategoryNm": "Alphabets",
              "providerNetwork": "ASKEE"
            },
            {
              "benefitCategoryId": "63GD",
              "cost": "876",
              "benefitCategoryNm": "Numbers",
              "providerNetwork": "1,2,3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "oopRemaining": "83",
        "planId": "1",
        "planName": "P1",
        "planPaidAmnt": "44",
      },
      {
        "memberCost": {
          "memberResponsibility": "97",
          "totalCostofOwnership": "23",
          "serviceCategory": [
            {
              "benefitCategoryId": "FJ87",
              "cost": "Left, Right",
              "benefitCategoryNm": "Directions",
              "providerNetwork": "JSKE"
            }
          ]
        },
        "oopRemaining": "12",
        "planId": "2",
        "planName": "P2",
        "planPaidAmnt": "74",
      },
      {
        "memberCost": {
          "memberResponsibility": "22",
          "totalCostofOwnership": "7",
          "serviceCategory": [
            {
              "benefitCategoryId": "78D3",
              "cost": "Jan, Feb",
              "benefitCategoryNm": "Months",
              "providerNetwork": "OPD7"
            }
          ]
        },
        "oopRemaining": "12",
        "planId": "3",
        "planName": "P3",
        "planPaidAmnt": "89",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now in UI all information is coming correctly except for `serviceCategory[]` array. In UI I have 3 cards. Each card has a category option. For first card it should display the serviceCategory details for first object and so on. But it displays all the serviceCategory details under each card. Example: First card should only show Alphabets: ABC and Numbers 123 under category column and second card should display Direction Left Right and third card should display the months Jan, Feb. But it is displaying alphabets, numbers, direction and months under category column for each card.

I have attached a stackblitz along. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-citshn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you don't need to make serviceDetails array and iterate again on it just continue with the above array i.e details, so you only need to replace this line

```
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="serviceCategoryMenu{{i}}" *ngFor="let sCD of serviceDetails; let j = index">
```

With this :

```
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="serviceCategoryMenu{{i}}" *ngFor="let sCD of details.memberCost.serviceCategory; let j = index">
```

It will work. I have tested it !! GOOD LUCK

Comment: thank you very much. This is working extremely well. I am new to Angular and I just want to know, how does ```let j = index``` work here. I have not assigned this index in my html to the category <li> tags then how does it read it? And is it completely independent of using id or planName as parameters to compare and assign? Will really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the inner `ngFor` isn't looping over the correct data.
You've written `<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="serviceCategoryMenu{{i}}" *ngFor="let sCD of serviceDetails; let j = index">` in the template.

Here you're trying to loop over `serviceDetails` which will always be the entire list of `serviceCategories`. This same variable is being used by all cards and therefore all cards would naturally have the same output.

One option is to change the way you're storing the data in `serviceDetails` and make it an Object with the key as the planId and the value an array of the associated `serviceCategories`. You could then loop over `serviceDetails[details.id]` which would give you the required output.

You could do this by omitting the third loop and have your code look like this:

```
.subscribe(
 (res: any) => {
   this.serviceDetails = {};
   for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i ++){
     for (let j = 0; j < res[i].planComparisonResultList.length; j ++) {
       let id=res[i].planComparisonResultList[j].id;
       this.serviceDetails[id]=res[i].planComparisonResultList[j].memberCost.serviceCategory
      // for ( let k = 0; k < res[i].planComparisonResultList[j].memberCost.serviceCategory.length; k ++) {
      // this.serviceDetails[id].push(res[i].planComparisonResultList[j].memberCost.serviceCategory[k]);
      // }
      if (j < 3) {
          this.uptoThreePlans.push(res[i].planComparisonResultList[j]);
            this.plans = this.uptoThreePlans;
            this.onePage = true;
            this.twoPages = false;
            this.threePages = false;                          
        }               
      else if ((j >= 3) && (j <6)) {
        this.uptoSixPlans.push(res[i].planComparisonResultList[j]);
        this.onePage = false;
        this.twoPages = true;
        this.threePages = false;
      }
      else {
        this.uptoNinePlans.push(res[i].planComparisonResultList[j]);
        this.onePage = false;
        this.twoPages = false;
        this.threePages = true;
      }
      }
     }       
   })
```

UPDATE:
Adding an explanation for the changes.
Earlier the code manipulating `serviceDetails` would end up as an Array of all available `serviceCategories`. As mentioned earlier using this as the input for the cards resulted in all cards having the same data, since the all referred to the same variable in the template.

To avoid that we've now made `serviceDetails` on object of the form `{id:[categories]}` where id is the unique id for that plan and its value being the array of categories available for that plan. Plan name could also be used as the key as long as it will always be unique.

As the value is always an array, we can use a directive like `ngFor` to loop over it. To access the array we need to simply call `serviceDetails[id]`. since id is present in the details variable created in the template we can refer to the array of categories for each plan via `serviceDetails[details.id]`. This ensures that we only get the categories for that specific plan when generating the view.

Comment: if possible can you please explain why did we change serviceDetails into an object? I mean ```*ngFor``` loop does not work on objects if I am not wrong. Can you explain the logic once? And the ID value how did you come up with that? Thank you

Comment: @Vishavgeet Check my answer below... May be that will help you more.

Comment: @Vishavgeet Ive updated the answer with an explanation, hope it helps!

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation. I now have two amazing methods to deal with the issue. Thank you guys!